# Swagger, BasicAuth: Set username and password

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, swagger, swagger-ui

I use Swagger and flask in python and generate a SwaggerUI page for it. I would like to save my API by authentication with username and password.
I have read throw all documentation but I do not understand: Where do I actually set the username and password?

I copied this into my yaml file:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    klingerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
security:
  - klingerAuth: []
```

This then adds lock-symbols to everything and adds an authorize button. But one can anyway access everything and the authorise button accepts everything as input for username and password.

So where to I actually define what could be accepted there?

[image]

Swagger is defined like this in my python programme:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
SWAGGER_URL = "/pathapi"
API_URL = "/pathapi/swagger.yaml"
swaggerui_blueprint = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
    SWAGGER_URL,
    API_URL,
    config={
        "app_name": "secret AI stuff"
    }
)
app.register_blueprint(swaggerui_blueprint, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)
```